# Change the way to access a local html page

Tags: node-red

I'm using node-red to run a HTML-page. like shown in the example:

[image]

to access this page, I have to call: `127.0.0.1:1880/hello`

my question is, is there a way to be able to call it just by using say : `hello` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how HTTP [URLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) work

You can access access it via the real IP address of the machine Node-RED running on as by default Node-RED binds to `0.0.0.0` which means all IP addresses on.